# Add inline style to pages where shortcode was used

Tags: shortcode, wp-enqueue-style, wp-head

I am trying to add a style to the header, using this method the style only loads on single posts but if I use a shortcode to load the post content that style does not load in the header:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'output_styles')
function output_styles($base_ID){
   $global post;
     echo '<style type="text/css">'. get_post_meta($post->ID, 'append_css') .'</style>';
}
```

in my shortcode I am passing the ID of the post, if I call the `ouput_styles` functions from shortcode function :

```
output_styles($pass_id);
```

then the content of `output_style` is printed but it is not in the header. It is right before the shortcode output.

How can I output the style in the header when using shortcodes?

Comment: Where are you putting the `add_action` code? If it's not in the `functions.php` inside the active theme you should transfer it there.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, [has_shortcode()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_shortcode/) is your friend.

First, we hook into [wp_print_styles](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_print_styles/), instead of `wp_head`.  In the func we hook
we check if the post contains our shortcode.  If it does, we get the CSS we want and output
it as an inlined `<style>`.

```
add_action ('wp_print_styles', 'wpse_enqueue_shortcode_css') ;

function
wpse_enqueue_shortcode_css ()
{
    global $post ;

    if (is_single () && has_shortcode ($post->post_content, 'my_shortcode')) {
        $append_css = get_post_meta ($post->ID, 'append_css', true) ;

        echo <<<EOF
        <style type='text/css'>
            $append_css
        </style>
EOF;
        }

    return ;
}
```

Comment: but `get_post_meta ($post->ID, 'append_css', true)` gets the meta for current post and not the one set using shortcode so wrong style will be loaded

Comment: in this case, the current post _is_ the post using the shortcode.

Comment: @Paul'SparrowHawk'Biron Alen wants to add the style if the *post indicated in the shortcode's attributes* contains the meta-data - not if the post containing the shortcode has the meta-data. By the time the shortcode retrieves the post which might have the meta-data, the `wp_head`/`wp_print_styles` actions will have already fired with `global $post` referencing the post containing the shortcode.

Comment: Does't work on the home page archive as it uses the same color for every post. @paul-sparrow-hawk-biron

Answer (score 0):

@bosco, thanx for the comment...I misunderstood what @Alen was trying to accomplish (the `global $post` in the code included in the question threw me off).

If my understanding is now correct, the following should do the trick (altho, it's a bit ugly).  It works by hooking into `wp_print_styles` **within** the function that processes the shortcode.

```
add_shortcode ('my_shortcode', 'my_shortcode') ;

function
my_shortcode ($atts)
{
    $defaults = array (
        'id' => '',
        // other atts for the shortcode
        ) ;
    $atts = shortcode_atts ($defaults, $atts) ;

    if (!empty ($atts['id'])) {
        global $my_shortcode_css ;

        // grab the CSS from the post whose ID was passed in the 'id' attribute of
        // my_shortcode, e.g., [my_shortcode id='123']
        // and store it in a global
        $my_shortcode_css = get_post_meta ($atts['id'], 'append_css', true) ;

        // no need to hook into wp_print_styles IF we don't have any CSS to output
        if (!empty ($my_shortcode_css)) {
            // hook into wp_print_styles with an anonymous func
            add_action ('wp_print_styles', function () {
                global $my_shortcode_css ;

                if (empty ($my_shortcode_css)) {
                    return ;
                    }

                echo <<<EOF
    <style type='text/css'>
        $my_shortcode_css
    </style>
EOF;

                // clean up, since we no longer need this global
                unset ($my_shortcode_css) ;
                }) ;
            }
        }

    // insert code to produce the output of the shortcode
    $output = ... ;

    return ($output) ;
}
```

**Note:** If you can conceive of `[my_shortcode]` being used more than once within a given post, it would probably be a good idea to add logic to the above to check whether CSS has already been output for a given post ID.  I'll leave that as an "exercise for the reader" :-)